# JQuery 1.12.3 (Datatables) conflicts with JQuery 1.7.2(JQuery-UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm pretty new at working with front-end but I'm finding JS quite useful for performing actions on the client side.

At the moment I'm serving a `flask` website with the default template.

This page used to only contain a `JQuery Datatable`

Recently I found the need to open a popup dialog with a pdf file(`iframe` inside `dialog`) but the imports are colliding and only work one of the two at the time.

The Datatable imports are the following ones:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    <style type="text/css" class="init"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

And the Popup thingy are those:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Without the `1.7.2` the table loads successfully but the UI crashes with the following error:

> jquery-ui.js:9833 Uncaught TypeError: $.curCSS is not a function

With it the datatable doesn't load:

> table:3704 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Although it's pretty ugly [here](https://gist.github.com/EndermanAPM/d5efeea963491cc93ddd6b5f030ef523) is the full template code.

Comment: use latest version of jQuery-ui

Comment: That actually did the job, stupid me, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Pranav C Balan in the comments I just had to use the more recent JQuery-ui versions and it worked flawlessly.

Here are the JQuery imports with the latest versions at the moment:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```